# Switching the order of integration doesn't work?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

We've been taught that you can change the order of integrations and it doesn't change the result (for common functions). However, this doesn't seem to be the case:

$$\int_{0}^{3} \int_0^1 3(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2+2 \,dx\,dy \neq \int_{0}^{1} \int_0^3 3(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2+2 \,dy\,dx$$

The result of the first one is $12$ while the second one equals $6$. Why doesn't it work here?

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \int_0^3 3(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2+2 \,dy\,dx & = \int_{0}^{1} \left.\left[3y(x-1)^2 + \frac{(y-2)^3}{3}+2y\right]\right|_0^3 dx \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} 9(x-1)^2 -\frac{1}{3}+6-\frac{8}{3} \,dx \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} 9(x-1)^2 + 3 \,dx \\
& = 3\int_{0}^{1} 3(x-1)^2 + 1 \,dx \\
& = 3\Big[(x-1)^3 + x\Big]\bigg|_0^1dx \\
& = 3 + 3 \\[0.3ex]
& = 6
\end{align}

Comment: Check your integration again.

Comment: Without looking, it's clear you must have made an error. Those integrals _must_ be equal.

Comment: Gonna include my calculations. I've been trying to find an error for more than an hour.

Comment: Yes: and $+ 8/3$, I can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton Could you please add a short answer explaining how you found your mistake, just so that this question doesn't sit in the "Unanswered" queue for another year? There's nothing wrong with [answering your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).